# I want to integrate pubnub with zendesk

Tags: javascript, php, add-on, pubnub, zendesk

is it possible to integrate zendesk to pubnub? I want to create a pubnub channel for each zendesk ticket, and when I respond to a ticket with some message I want to send pubnub api request to record that message at pubnub server.
basically, I want an user interface to handle customer queries, and this chat between user and me I want to save it at pubnub servers. Any idea?

Comment: If you have the ability to create a custome plugin for ZenDesk, then yes, it is possible to use one of the PubNub SDKs. I know they have a REST API but assume they have something like Ruby or Node SDK. Let us know what you need to know to get started.

Comment: In zendesk when I reply to a ticket I need to call pubnub api to record that reply msg to pubnub servers, but I dont have idea how will I call pubnub api, If I had zendesk source code (something like php website on localhost or my web erver), i could have inserted my pubnub api calls code in it.

But now I dont have control over source code of zendesk, any way I can integrate pubnub api call with it?

Answer (score 2):

## Zendesk Custom App Using PubNub

You don't need Zendesk's source code (and you can't get it anyway). The right thing to do is to create a [Zendesk app](https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/agent/introduction) by using [their REST API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api).

Within that custom app, you use PubNub's REST API or a PubNub SDK that is compatible with whatever Zendesk offers as languages to use for add-ons (Ruby, Node, whatever they offer).

This is a cool use case (Zendesk, Desk Freshdesk, etc) with add-ons because you can do things within Zendesk that use PubNub to react to actions and trigger other things to happen or notify other agents in Zendesk.

You can also create a standalone app (web, server or mobile) that can subscribe to channels that the Zendesk is publishing to and you can go the other way around. The standalone app can publish on a channel that the Zendesk add-on is subscribed to and react to that message as required. The *what* to do is limitless.

And the standalone app could just be some other product/service/platform that allows you to create a custom app: Salesforce.com, Hipchat, Slack, Flowdock, Socialcast, Jive, Yammer, Workday, Zenefits, Zuora,  whatever!

Here is a [Zendesk custom app example](https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/agent/example) to get you started.

Since you were referencing PHP, you might be creating a server side process that will interact with your Zendesk custom app so you will need [PubNub PHP SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/php/pubnub-php-sdk). But you might be able to use [PubNub JavaScript SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) within the Zendesk custom app.

Let us know if you need help taking the next step here after you get familiar with how to [get started with a Zendesk app](https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/agent/getting_started).

Comment: Please let me know if you still have questions about this. But if this was helpful getting you started, please accept as the answer.